# can you give me a scenario where default class loader of java is not suitable and we need customized class loader

Tags: java, jvm

I am new to the class loading concept. I know there is three default class loader in java. But i want to know what situation we must go for default class loader.

Answer (score 1):

Most Java developers never need to directly use a custom class loader.

Custom class loaders are typically used by applications that need to load classes at runtime. 
Some examples are:
Application servers like tomcat employ class loaders to load the classes within war files.

Frameworks like OSGI use class loaders to limit class scope to individual components within an application.

The spring-boot loader project uses class loaders to build "fat" jars loading the classes from nested jars before starting the desired main class.

Software like jrebel use class loaders to allow you to make code changes to an application without redeploying it.